# js undefined после присовения результата функции перемннной

Tags: javascript, массивы

Функция getCountSteps вызывает внутри себя функцию step. В функции step перед return стоит console.log с возвращаемым массивом, который выводится как и ожидается. В функции getCountSteps записывается результат функции step в переменную, после чего console.log возвращается undefined

Код: https://jsfiddle.net/jcz8g7he/

```
const getStepsCount = items => {
  /*Временное (или нет) решение для подсчета кол-ва ходов
  Закрашиваем все поле в тот цвет, ячеек которого больше всего
  Находим другой цвет и закрашиваем в наш
  Пока не закрасим все поле, кол-во итераций будет кол-вом шагов (возможно +1)*/

  const count = items.length; //Кол-во ячеек
  let colorsCount = {}; //Объект цвет = его кол-во
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) { //Идем по всему массиву
    for (let j = 0; j < count; j++) {
      if (colorsCount.hasOwnProperty(items[i][j])) { //Если уже был такой цвет, увеличиваем его кол-во
        colorsCount[items[i][j]]++;
      }
      else { //Иначе, создаем
        colorsCount[items[i][j]] = 1;
      }
    }
  }
  const mainColor = Object.keys(colorsCount).reduce((result, item) => colorsCount[item] > colorsCount[result] ? item : result); //Цвет которого больше всего
  console.log(mainColor);
  let stepsCount = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) { //Идем по всем ячейкам
    for (let j = 0; j < count; j++) {
      if (items[i][j] != mainColor) { //Если ячейка не основного цвета, заменяем и счиатем шаги
        console.log('i = ' + i);
        console.log('j = ' + j);
        console.log(items[i][j]);
        items = step(items, i, j, items[i][j], mainColor);
        stepsCount++;
        console.log(items);
      }
    }
  }

  console.log(stepsCount);
}



const step = (items, row, column, colorOriginal, color, stack = []) => {
  /*
  Идем от стартовой ячейки во все стороны заменяя все возможные ячейки. 
  Все замененные ячейки сохраняем в массив.
  Достаем последний элемент массива и кидаем в эту функцию в качестве главного элемента, из массива удаляем 
  Продолжаем пока массив не будет пуст
  */

  if (color == colorOriginal) { //Если заменяем цвет на такой же, возвращаем 0
    return 0;
  }

  items[column][row] = color;
  let check = true;
  let i = 0;

  while (check) { //Идем "вверх"
    i++;
    if (column - i + 1 > 0) { //Если не верхняя ячейка и нужный цвет
      if (items[column - i][row] == colorOriginal) {        
        items[column - i][row] = color; //Заменяем цвет
        stack.push({'column': column - i, 'row': row}); //Добавляем ячейку в стек для дальнейшних проверок
      }
    }
    else { //Иначе выходим с цикла
      check = false;
      i = 0;
    }
  }

  while (!check) { //Идем "вниз"
    i++;
    if (column + i < items.length) { //Если не нижняя ячейка и нужный цвет
      if (items[column + i][row] == colorOriginal) {
        items[column + i][row] = color; //Заменяем цвет
        stack.push({'column': column + i, 'row': row}); //Добавляем ячейку в стек для дальнейшних проверок
      }
    }
    else { //Иначе выходим с цикла
      check = true;
      i = 0;
    }
  }

  while (check) { //Идем "влево"
    i++;
    if (row - i + 1 > 0) { //Если не левая ячейка и нужный цвет
      if (items[column][row - i] == colorOriginal) {
        items[column][row - i] = color; //Заменяем цвет
        stack.push({'column': column, 'row': row - i}); //Добавляем ячейку в стек для дальнейшних проверок
      }
    }
    else { //Иначе выходим с цикла
      check = false;
      i = 0;
    }
  }

  while (!check) { //Идем "вправо"
    i++;
    if (row + i < items.length) { //Если не правая ячейка и нужный цвет
      if (items[column][row + i] == colorOriginal) {
        items[column][row + i] = color; //Заменяем цвет
        stack.push({'column': column, 'row': row + i}); //Добавляем ячейку в стек для дальнейшних проверок
      }
    }
    else { //Иначе выходим с цикла
      check = true;
      i = 0;
    }
  }

  if (stack.length != 0) { //Если массив не пустой
    const temp = stack.pop(); //Берем последний элемент
    step(items, temp.row, temp.column, colorOriginal, color, stack); //Заменяем от "последнего" элемента
  }

  else {
    console.log(items);
    return items; //Когда стек пуст, возвращаем новый массив
  }
}

const items = [
  [
    "itemGreen",
    "itemGreen",
    "itemGreen",
    "itemBlue"
  ],
  [
    "itemBlue",
    "itemGreen",
    "itemGreen",
    "itemGreen"
  ],
  [
    "itemGreen",
    "itemBlue",
    "itemGreen",
    "itemBlue"
  ],
  [
    "itemGreen",
    "itemBlue",
    "itemGreen",
    "itemBlue"
  ]
];

getStepsCount(items);
```

Надеюсь понятно в чем вопрос. Перед return стоит console.log и все ок, но после присвоения в перемннную результата этой функции, значение становится undefined. Не понимаю почему
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вас в getStepsCount нет return

Comment: Спасибо, но в данном вопросе это роли не играет. Ошибка в другом.

Comment: А что у вас функция `step` возвращает, когда `stack.length != 0`?

Comment: Ничего. Она рекурсиваная и как только элементы в stack закончатся, вернет items.

Comment: @Gelloiss, вернет items, и потеряет их, так как этот результат никуда не сохраняется, либо пробрасывается дальше

Comment: не хватает return перед `step(items, temp.row,...`, плюс данная функция в некоторых случаях возвращает число, в некоторых - массив, а в вызываемом коде всегда ожидается массив

Comment: В случае если stack != 0 оно передается items обратно в функцию step и продолжает обрабатывать массив. Возвращает данные ЛИШЬ когда stack == 0. Это в самом конце функции как раз. И перед return стоит console.log, который вывод массив нормально. Но при присвоении результата функции переменной рано или поздно идет возврат undefined @Grundy

Comment: @Grundy Число возвращает она для других целей, чтобы сделать проверку. В данном вопросе это значения не имеет и никогда числа она не вернет. Но если я поставлю return перед step(items, ...) она же перестанет быть рекурсивной. Мне нужно вернуть items лишь когда stack уже пустой. Это происходит в ветке else.

Comment: @Grundy если вставить return перед step(items, temp.row,... то код после return`a же просто не выполнится. Функция не будет выполнять всего своего необходимого функционала

Comment: Я только учу JS. Возможно, правильно было бы
    return step(items, temp.row, temp.column, colorOriginal, color, stack);?

Comment: Да, так попробуйте.

Comment: _Но если я поставлю return перед step(items, ...) она же перестанет быть рекурсивной._ - почему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решил. В JS чтобы работала рекурсивная функция надо сделать так

```
const func = i => {
  if (i != 10) {
    i++;
    return func(i);
  }
  else return 0;
}
```

а не вот так, как я пробовал изначально

```
const func = i => {
  if (i != 10) {
    i++;
    func(i);
  }
  else return 0;
}
```